# The relationship between $p$-solvable Group and solvable group

Tags: gr.group-theory

Can anyone please tell me The relationship between $p$-solvable Group
and solvable group.and find an example of a $p$-solvable group that is not solvable group or vice-versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A finite group is solvable if an only if it is $p$-solvable for every prime $p$. An example of a $p$-solvable group which is not solvable is the semidirect product $G = VSL(2,5)$, where $V$ is an elementary Abelian group of order $121$, and $SL(2,5)$ acts faithfully and irreducibly as a group of linear transformations on $V$. The group $G$ is $11$-solvable, but is not solvable.

Later edit: Easier, but perhaps less interesting, is that a non-Abelian finite simple group $G$ is $p$-solvable if and only if the prime $p$ does not divide $|G|$. More generally, any finite group $G$ is $p$-solvable for all but finitely many primes $p$.

(Recall that a finite group $G$ is $p$-solvable for a prime $p$ if and only if every composition factor of $G$ is either of order $p$ or of order prime to $p$.
It is in fact true that a finite group $G$ is solvable if and only if $G$ is $2$-solvable, but this requires the very deep Feit-Thompson Theorem that groups of odd order are solvable).

Comment: Nice answer, but I can't help but feel that the question would have been a better fit on MSE (though coming up with a non-trivial example of a non-solvable but $p$-solvable group is not trivial).

Comment: This is probably a case where group theorists know what a p-solvable group is, but lots of non-specialists don't. I agree it's not research level for finite group-theorists! If people ask non-trivial questions in what seems to be good faith, I am usually not inclined to tell them to go elsewhere, but mostly leave my answers as comments.

Comment: I agree that it is a somewhat specialized concept. But the first google hit (for me at least) is the groupprops page on the topic, which states the connection. But again, the example (and how non-trivial it can be to come up with) makes me not want to move the question.